# Regression models with several samples of the same people

Tags: regression, bias, cross-section

I am trying to implement some regression models with my data of 56 features x 1500 samples to fit a response variable of 1x1500 and I am hesitating about the statistical validity of what I am trying to do.

This dataset has been created with data of 51 people, therefore, several samples have been collected from the same people at different times. The response variable is the result of a cognitive test for each one of the subjects, and has been acquired only once. Consequently, we have n samples of each subject, having all of them the same value at the response variable.

I have put the data all together, mixing data of all the people, to create my models. The number of samples for each subject is not exactly the same...

Am I biasing my models with introducing the same labels repeated times? Should I consider computing the mean values for each subject to create a unique sample for each one of them? Can such a dataset be called "Cross-sectional"?

Thank you very much,

Comment: I would recommend an approach which takes into account and exploits the clustering features, eg a mixed linear model or generalizing estimating equations.